# How to get css attribute of a lxml element?

Tags: python, css, lxml

I want to find a fast function to get all style properties of a lxml element that take into account the css stylesheet, the style attribute element and tackle the herit issue.

For example :

html :

```
<body>
  <p>A</p>
  <p id='b'>B</p>
  <p style='color:blue'>B</p>
</body>
```

css :

```
body {color:red;font-size:12px}
p.b {color:pink;}
```

python :

```
elements = document.xpath('//p')
print get_style(element[0]) 
>{color:red,font-size:12px}
print get_style(element[1]) 
>{color:pink,font-size:12px}
print get_style(element[2]) 
>{color:blue,font-size:12px}
```

Thanks

Comment: Since what you want is not XML parsing but HTML/CSS *interpretation*, this is not covered by lxml.

Comment: Sorry, but the only thing that does what you want is a browser. There's no way of resolving CSS rules without implementing a big mess of HTML, CSS and DOM specs. What a mess, eh?

Comment: Yes i know but i want a function that can do it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a combination of lxml and [cssutils](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils). [This](http://code.google.com/p/cssutils/source/browse/trunk/examples/style.py) cssutils utility module should be able to do what you're asking. Install cssutils along with that module, then run the following code:

```
from style import *

html = """<body>
    <p>A</p>
    <p id='b'>B</p>
    <p style='color:blue'>B</p>
</body>"""

css = """body {color:red;font-size:12px}
p {color:yellow;}
p.b {color:green;}"""


def get_style(element, view):
    if element != None:
        inline_style = [x[1] for x in element.items() if x[0] == 'style']
        outside_style =  []
        if view.has_key(element):
            outside_style = view[element].getCssText()
        r = [[inline_style, outside_style]]
        r.append(get_style(element.getparent(), view))
        return r
    else:
        return None

document = getDocument(html)
view = getView(document, css)

elements = document.xpath('//p')
print get_style(elements[0], view)
```

Comment: Not really, it do not tackle the herit issue. get_style(element[0]) -> {}

Comment: print get_style(elements[0], view) ->  {color:yellow;} but i haven't font-size because herit doesn't work

Comment: I update my example, it's more correct now. In this case the get_style(elements[0], view) -> {} however the color may be red

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting, but i think not realy scalable to catch fast all css property of a web page