# Finding background images programmatically

Tags: python, html, css, lxml, python-requests

In the process of trying to use goose extractor for a project I've found that it's generally too brittle for my use case, and missed top_images very frequently.

As a result I'm setting out to make my own goose extractor! For those unfamiliar, given a url, goose extractor automatically recognizes things like top_image, main_text, etc...

For things wrapped in `img` tags this is a pretty straightforward task. For things using an inline style to set the background image it's also very doable.

My question is, if a page has a css attribute set on a node, is there any way of programmatically accessing that attribute? I'm using requests/lxml, but I can generalize.

```
import requests
import lxml

parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser()
document = lxml.parse(requests.get(<url>).content, parser)
# Does something like this exist?
document.grab_elements(<with background-image set in css>)
```

I've looked through the `lxml` docs and done a fair bit of googling, but I really can't find anything about this. I know that it's totally possible if I, say, read through the `<head>` section, download the stylesheets and parse them, but that feels REALLY heavy-handed compared to an xpath query.

Comment: You _might_ be able to do what you want using a combination of lxml and cssutils, as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9520444/4014959) to "How to get css attribute of a lxml element?". But AFAIK, the only truly robust way to do it is to build the page & inspect its contents, eg via its DOM. However, I'm not an expert on this topic & am happy to be corrected.

Comment: @PM2Ring That... seems doable. Kind of falls under the bottom caveat, but if you want to put up some example code and nobody  swoops in with a better solution I'll accept it.